how can i preview components in self-host?
first, my components can preview in my localhost server when i use bit start, like thisimage1,image2.
but when i use bit export to my bit-server which start with docker by this doc:https://github.com/teambit/bit/blob/master/scripts/docker-teambit-bit/README.md, those components can display on the website, but the preview page and docs are no working.
image3,image4.
so what can i do for this problems? it takes me a lot of time..

the exported component is likely not build. please run bit tag --build before you export. i recommend running bit tag --build --unmodified now to get both your components rebuilt, as they are not modified.

Thank you immensely. It has now achieved success. This question has been a persistent concern for me.

By default Bit does not run the build pipeline for components, as generally it expects you to run CI for it. As part of the component CI pipeline, all documentations and rendering gets generated. Not seeing them means the CI pipeline didn't ran.
So when you bit tag && bit export to a scope (self hosted or not, it's the same behavior), you need to do is have Bit run the build pipeline as part of the tag command.
There are two ways to do it, depending on how you aim to control versining:

Using the --build option ie bit tag --build, which will use the default versioning mechanism for Bit.
Running bit tag --soft to define the versions you want to tag, and then bit tag --persist to "actualize" them.

Once done, you can run bit export, and all relevant build artifacts will be available on the remote, so features like rendering will work as expected.
